In Pytorch, how to parallelize different models on Batch？
When I was training the model, I needed to iterate through each batch, which is definitely inefficient.
The code is as follows
            for batch, indices in enumerate(topk_indices):
                indices = indices.tolist()

                for i in range(self.n_random_expert):
                    random_expert_idx = -1
                    while random_expert_idx == -1:
                        random_expert_idx = random.randint(0, self.n_channels - 1)
                        if random_expert_idx not in indices:
                            indices.append(random_expert_idx)
                        else:
                            random_expert_idx = -1

                for idx, indice in enumerate(indices):
                    net = getattr(self, self.ch_names[indice] + '_' + self.attr_type)
                    if self.attr_type == 'ExpertBase':
                        expert_output[batch:, idx * self.n_expert_hidden_dim:(idx + 1) * self.n_expert_hidden_dim,
                        :] = self.dropout(net(x[batch:, idx, :]))

Is there a way to make this code can be faster?
Since each batch might have a different model, I can't think of a way to parallelize it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
